# Best way to generate code in C# similar to using decorators?

Tags: c#

Say I have a pattern that I'm constantly repeating. Something like:

```
static class C {
  [DllImport("mydll")]
  private static extern uint MyNativeCall1(Action a);
  public static uint MyWrapper1(Action a) {
    // Do something
    return MyNativeCall1(a);
  }

  [DllImport("mydll")]
  private static extern uint MyNativeCall2(Action a);
  public static uint MyWrapper2(Action a) {
    // Do something
    return MyNativeCall2(a);
  }

  //...

  [DllImport("mydll")]
  private static extern uint MyNativeCallN(Action a);
  public static uint MyWrapperN(Action a) {
    // Do something
    return MyNativeCallN(a);
  }
}
```

The only thing different in all those is the name of the native function and wrapper method. Is there a way to generate them via something like decorators? At first I thought C# attributes were decorators. That is, that I could generate the code via something like `[GenerateScaffolding("MyNativeCall1")]`. But it seems attributes are more like annotations, instantiating a class that holds some metadata.

Neither does C# have macros. So is there any way to do this?

A few things to keep in mind:

- The idea is that the wrapper methods have extra code; they are not merely calling the native functions.
- The idea is also that the generated code can be interleaved with other existing code inside a class and not to generate the class file itself; something like either decorators or C/C++ macros.
- The approach should not depend on any particular IDE. Specifically, I'm not on Visual Studio.

Comment: You could use [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)?

Comment: Why aren't you use the `EntryPoint` property of `DllImport` to specify different name for the methods being called?

Comment: `[DllImport("mydll", EntryPoint = "MyNativeCall1")] public static extern uint MyWrapper1(Action a);`

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz because I might have to do more than merely call the native function inside the wrapper method; something I forgot to make more obvious.

Comment: If you have a list of the methods beforehand, have you looked into reflection or emitting the IL yourself? This is pretty deep and nasty stuff, but could well work.

Comment: You might consider writing such classes in another language such as Nemerle, which does include templates. The syntax is similar, and it will almost certainly be supported on your platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my own, with a sad: NOPE. There's no way to do this in C#. That is, there's nothing in the language itself nor frameworks.

If, however, one is on Visual Studio, there's templates, like RGraham and Pradeep pointed out; other IDEs might have different facilities / features to accomplish this too. But again, nothing like a preprocessor or decorators in C# itself.

Comment: Not just Visual Studio, but any IDE which supports pre/post-build commands (therefore being able to execute bash/shell). Any IDE worth it's salt should support these.

Answer (score 10):

Taking the idea from this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx) on T4 Templates, you could so something like:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
static class C {
<#  
    int N = 15;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    { #>
    [DllImport("mydll")]
    private static extern uint MyNativeCall<#= i #>(Action a);
    public static uint MyWrapper<%#= i #>(Action a) {
        return MyNativeCall<#= i #>(a);
    }
<# }  #>
}
```

Comment: I'll take this if there's no better way. But these templates look kind of fugly. I'll read more about them in a bit, but do you know if A:They can be interleaved with the rest of the code in a class? Like, not to generate the file itself but merely insert text in a file I'm working on (more ala C/C++ macros) B:Is it a VS feature only? Cause I'm not using VS. I should add these details to my question.

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz You can write the base definition in T4 then use the *include file* syntax to include any existing code. Yes, this is a Visual Studio feature which generates the code before sending it to the compiler - so it's not going to work for your situation. Sounds like you just want a pre-build shell/batch/other script, but this is not part of C# so is always going to be dependant on whatever IDE you're using.

Comment: I actually wanted, short of decorators, at least something like the C preprocessor, which any compiler recognizes :/

Comment: @SaldaVonSchwartz Sorry, there's nothing like this in the C# language spec.

Comment: C# does not have a preprocessor. You're going to have to rely on tooling outside of the actual compiler. The .tt system *can* be used outside of Visual Studio, but usually with some manual work.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the IDE to generate and process templates at runtime, but you have to [**create your own directive processor**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bb126542%28v=VS.120,d=hv.2%29.aspx) and/or [**host**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126579.aspx).

```
Engine engine = new Engine();

//read the text template
string input = File.ReadAllText(templateFileName);

//transform the text template
string output = engine.ProcessTemplate(input, host);
```

In your template, you can mix template language with C# code (sample HTML generation):

```
<table>
  <# for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
     { #>
        <tr><td>Test name <#= i #> </td>
          <td>Test value <#= i * i #> </td> 
        </tr>
  <# } #>
</table>
```

Here is how I use T4 to [**generate all kinds of state machines**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/658841/Using-T-templates-for-Finite-State-Machine-genera) from text files.

You can even generate source code for [**C# class at runtime, compile and load**](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime) and execute from your program.

If you combine all those techniques, perhaps even with composable parts, like [**MEF**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I'm sure you will be able to achieve what you need.

**UPDATE** *without MEF, but you still need IDE to pre-process the template.*

Since I don't have your DLL, I can't give you an exact answer, but perhaps this will help.

Given this template (ExtDll.tt):

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="mscorlib" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<# 
            var extraCodeArray = new[]
                             { string.Empty,
                                 "var localVar = 1;",
                                 "var localVar = 2;",
                                 "var localVar = 3;",
                                 "var localVar = 4;",
                                 "var localVar = 5;",
                                 "var localVar = 6;",
                                 "var localVar = 7;",
                                 "var localVar = 8;",
                                 "var localVar = 9;",
                                 "var localVar = 10;",
                             };

#>
using System;
static class C{
<# for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
       { #>
       public static double MyWrapper<#= i #>(Func<int,double> a) {
         <#= extraCodeArray[i] #>
       return a.Invoke(localVar);
       }
    <# } #>
}
```

and this Program:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Reflection;

    using Microsoft.CSharp;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExtDll code = new ExtDll();
            string source = code.TransformText();
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters()
                                            {
                                                GenerateInMemory = true,
                                                GenerateExecutable = false
                                            };
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(
                new[]
                {
                    "System.Core.dll",
                    "mscorlib.dll"
                });
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);
            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                var errorString = String.Join("\n", results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().Select(error => String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText)));

                throw new InvalidOperationException(errorString);
            }
            Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
            Func<int,double> squareRoot = (i) => { return Math.Sqrt(i); };
            Type type = assembly.GetType("C");
            //object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("MyWrapper4");
            Console.WriteLine(method.Invoke(null, new object[]{squareRoot})); 
        }
    }

}
```

it will print 2, since it is a square root of 4.

**UPDATE 2**

After slightly modifying the CustomCmdLineHost from the second link above:

```
    public IList<string> StandardAssemblyReferences
    {
        get
        {
            return new string[]
            {
                //If this host searches standard paths and the GAC,
                //we can specify the assembly name like this.
                //---------------------------------------------------------
                //"System"

                //Because this host only resolves assemblies from the 
                //fully qualified path and name of the assembly,
                //this is a quick way to get the code to give us the
                //fully qualified path and name of the System assembly.
                //---------------------------------------------------------
                typeof(System.Uri).Assembly.Location,
                typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly.Location
            };
        }
    }
```

the sample program no longer requires the IDE:

```
        var host = new CustomCmdLineHost();
        host.TemplateFileValue = "ExtDll.tt";
        Engine engine = new Engine();
        string input = File.ReadAllText("ExtDll.tt");
        string source = engine.ProcessTemplate(input, host);
        if (host.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            var errorString = String.Join("\n", host.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().Select(error => String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText)));

            throw new InvalidOperationException(errorString);            
        }

        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
... rest of the code as before
```

I hope this satisfies your needs.

**UPDATE 3**

If you further modify the sample host like this:

```
internal string TemplateFileValue = Path.Combine(
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"CustomCmdLineHost.tt");
```

Then you can avoid having to specify the template file name and just use in-memory processing:

```
var host = new CustomCmdLineHost();
Engine engine = new Engine();
string input = File.ReadAllText("ExtDll.tt");
string source = engine.ProcessTemplate(input, host);
```

Enjoy and kindly mark your preferred answer.

Answer (score 4):

Code snippets in Visual Studio exist for this purpose only.

Have a look at this MSDN article that teaches you how to create your own custom code snippets.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

**EDIT:**

OK.. I see that you edited your question and added that you are not looking for an IDE specific feature. So my reply becomes irrelevent now. Nevertheless, it may be useful for someone who comes searching for this problem and is looking for a built in Visual Studio feature.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, with a little bit of PostSharp's AOP pixie dust:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

using PostSharp.Aspects;

internal class Program
{
    #region Methods

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action action = () => { Console.WriteLine("Action called."); };
        Console.WriteLine(C.MyWrapper1(action));
    }

    #endregion
}

[Scaffolding(AttributeTargetMembers = "MyWrapper*")]
internal static class C
{
    #region Public Methods and Operators

    public static uint MyWrapper1(Action a)
    {
        DoSomething1();
        return Stub(a);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private static void DoSomething1() { Console.WriteLine("DoSomething1"); }

    private static uint Stub(Action a) { return 0; }

    #endregion
}

internal static class ExternalStubClass
{
    #region Public Methods and Operators

    public static uint Stub(Action a)
    {
        a.Invoke();
        return 5;
    }

    #endregion
}

[Serializable]
public class ScaffoldingAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    #region Fields

    private MethodInfo doSomethingInfo;

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods and Operators

    public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
    {
        Type type = typeof(C);
        this.doSomethingInfo = type.GetMethod(method.Name.Replace("MyWrapper", "DoSomething"), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        this.doSomethingInfo.Invoke(null, null);
        args.ReturnValue = ExternalStubClass.Stub(args.Arguments[0] as Action);
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This sample basically shows, how a method in one class, can be dynamically overridden by a method from another class with the same name. The original Stub in C will never get called. You will have to obey some naming conventions.

If you combine it with [**Dynamically bound native DLL methods**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11310/DLLImport-with-dynamically-bound-native-DLLs-using), you will achieve scaffolding you require IMHO.